# Term for partially abbreviating names

Tags: single-word-requests, names

Is there a name for the tabloid media practice of part-initializing, part-abbreviating people's names?

E.g.  Jennifer Lopez -> J-Lo, Robert Pattinson -> R-Patz and so on.

Comment: Annoying, is what I call it.

Comment: My favorite truncation of this type is the one for the New York Knicks' all-star center (now retired) Patrick Ewing: P-Ew.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's a ***diminutive***,  or a *nickname* (although *nickname* implies somewhat more familiarity to my ears, it is used in the news as such: “Jennifer Lopez, known by her nickname J-Lo”).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could probably just call these nicknames — they are highly stylized nicknames, but nicknames nonetheless.